# How can I hide the date on the x axis?

Tags: d3.js

Say I have a simple time series graph with data for February 25th, 2013, starting from 1am and ending at 11pm. If I graph this data, I will have nice, even ticks on my x-axis 3 hours apart: 3am, 6am, 9am, etc. This is exactly what I want. However, at the beginning of the axis it shows 'Mon 25'. I'd like to hide this, and only show the hours.

I have read through d3's [time documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time) but cannot find an answer. Is there an easy way to do this, keeping my dates as Javascript objects? (I'm sure I could convert to strings, but I'd like to avoid this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`tickFormat()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#wiki-tickFormat) function to pass in a date formatter. The documentation isn't terribly clear, but links to [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4149176) that illustrates how to do it. In your case, you would have only a single entry in what is `customTimeFormat` in that example.